# Writing text in textbox and combo box at same time

Tags: vb6

Is there a way that I can write text in textbox, as well as in a combo box at the same time? When I type characters into the textbox, every character must also be added to the combo box at the same time.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

have your keydown event write that key to either or

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733630(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733630%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same text to appear in the combo box as the text box, then this is quite easy:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```